# Fourier series expansion of a $L^2$ function.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces

For a function $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ (where $\mathbb{T}$ denotes the unit circle) I know that it can be expressed as $f(z) = \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty}f_j z^j$. The Fourier coefficients are given by $f_j = \langle f, z^j\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}$.  My doubt is regarding finding the Fourier series expansion of a function $f$ which is defined as
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}1\quad  \text{if}\quad z= e^{i\theta},\: \theta \in [0,\pi]\\
0\quad \text{if}\quad z= e^{i\theta},\: \theta \in (\pi,2\pi) \end{cases}$$

I have attempted to compute the Fourier coefficients of $f$ and found them as $ f_j = 0 \quad \text{if $j$ is even and} \quad \frac{1}{πij} \quad \text {if $j$ is even}$.

Thus, $f(z)= \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{πi(2j+1)}$. However the final answer doesn't seem right. But at the same time I don't know where am I doing a mistake.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do not use $i$ for a running index when complex numbers are involved.

Comment: Why not just compute the coefficients using the inner product?

Comment: I have attempted it as follows: $f(z) = \sum_{m= -\infty}^{\infty}f_m z^m$, here $f_m = <f, z^m> = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(z) z^-{m}$

Comment: I have attempted it as follows: $f(z) = \sum_{m= -\infty}^{\infty}f_m z^m$, here $f_m = <f, z^m> = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(z) z^{-m} =   \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-im\theta} d\theta = 0 \ \text{if m is even and} \frac{1}{\pi i m} \ \text{if m is even}$. Thus, $f(z) = \sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi i (2k +1)}$. However the final answer doesnt seem right. But at the same time I dont know where am I doing a mistake.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy : Kindly see to my attempt. Thanks

Comment: What is the given answer?